# Selecting all clips on the right of the playhead

Tags: final-cut-pro

In Final Cut Pro 7, is it possible to select all clips and transitions on the right of the playhead with a shortcut?

Comment: Is there a way to mark LEFT of the playhead?

Answer (score 1):

There's something close to it. If you press 't' you will be using the Select Track Forward Tool which selects every visual OR audio track after and including the track you click on. If you press 'tttt' you will be using the Select All Tracks Forward Tool which selects everything including audio and audio transitions after and including the track you click on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing "tttt", just do "tt" and then "Shift (⇧)". This will be the same as "tttt", but "much" faster.